# How to deploy an Oracle APEX mobile application to a mobile device by newbies?

Tags: deployment, oracle-apex, mobile-application, oracle-apex-5

I am finding a solution for deploying an Oracle APEX application to a mobile phone. The solution I target on is for instructional purpose, hence should be easy to realize by newbies. I read a few solutions on the Internet, and here's my own comparison about them:

1. [Using the Oracle Mobile Application Framework](https://blogs.oracle.com/blueberry/want-to-bring-your-apex-application-to-ios-and-android-you-should-consider-the-oracle-mobile-application-framework): Frankly, after reading the document I have no idea of what steps I should do to deploy my mobile app by using it.
2. [The solution mentioned in this PDF](http://nyoug.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/APEX-5.1-Mobile-NYOUG-MSewtz.pdf): Towards the end of the document, it mentions the deployment of APEX mobile apps to Android and iOS devices. However, it only tells using Android Studio and Safari + XCode for testing and debugging, but not exactly telling are these software used for deployment as well. Another downside is that the resulting app is actually a set of webpages that can only be accessed by mobile web browsers, not a standalone mobile app installed in one's mobile phone.
3. [The online website introduced in this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fE137xnwCVM): This seems to be the easiest solution, online converting the uploaded APEX application to an .apk file. But the drawback is, it only works for Android devices. I can't find an equivalent for iOS devices. Plus, as I expect, it may not work 100% for every application.

Actually, are there any other ways for deploying an Oracle APEX mobile application that can be easy to realize, easy to understand and work in both Android and iOS devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it really depends on your level of expectation. 
APEX applications are webpages, you could just open up your phone's browser and open up the application. If you're using the Universal Theme, you just need to design your application for 4 inches.

At the very least, you could use a tool like Cordova (PhoneGap) to act as a app shell (for the relevant phone model) which runs the URL for you. You'll probably be familiar with a few of these style of applications already - common in banking.

Using Cordova also opens access to APIs that allow you to communicate with phone services, such as notifications, GPS details etc.